# Propper way to stop a thrift TThreadPoolAsyncServer in .net standard

Tags: c#, rpc, thrift

I've created a `TThreadPoolAsyncServer` witch is working correctly.

```
_server = new TThreadPoolAsyncServer(
                 processorFactory: new TSingletonProcessorFactory( processor ),
                 serverTransport: serverSocket,
                 inputTransportFactory: new TFramedTransport.Factory(),
                 outputTransportFactory: new TFramedTransport.Factory(),
                 inputProtocolFactory: new TBinaryProtocol.Factory(),
                 outputProtocolFactory: new TBinaryProtocol.Factory(),
                 threadConfig: new TThreadPoolAsyncServer.Configuration(),
                 logger: _logger );
```

But when I trigger the cancelationtoken from `_server.ServeAsync( cancellationtoken );`, the task does not complete.
When I use the `_server.Stop();` function the server eventually stops but the server also logs some not so nice looking errors:

```
      Thrift.Transport.TTransportException: System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed
```

What is the intended way to stop the `TThreadPoolAsyncServer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who stumbles upon this, this will be fixed in version 15.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-5398